# Cycles is crashing

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have a Lenovo 330 Ideapad. I've been using Blender 2.76 because Blender 2.79  that I used to use on another computer crashes. I have been most conformable with 2.76. As the lighting was quite bright on the normal render mode, my friend suggested switching my mode to Cycles, and I was interested, so I switched the modes, but the second I did it, my Blender crashed. I need help as I am making something for someone and I need better lighting. If there is an alternative way to change the lighting to less bright but still visible, please list it below! Thank you for taking your time!

Comment: afaik there are several Lenovo 330 Ideapad configurations out there. Please make sure to give us [all the relevant information](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please) about your system by [editing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/142786/edit) your question.

Comment: There can be several reasons why Blender is crashing. In order to help we'd need more information, for example any error message that is displayed. The most common reason is that you're running out of memory and your operating system's OOM killer stops the process. In order to diagnose the problem see the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/141734/mov-file-wont-import/141735#141735